# Turning off Fabric real-time monitoring

Tags: crashlytics

I have accidentally enabled real-time monitoring in Fabric, but I only want to use Crashlytics. How do I disable the real-time monitoring?

Comment: What do you mean? Fabric offers getting crash reports and analytics in real-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

If you want Answers data collection disabled, email support(at)fabric(dot)io with the app's bundle id or package name.